# Get Average from range with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet with 6 columns. The first column has the customer name, the 5th column has a number that I want to get an average of for all occurrences of a specific customer name.

I have tried the `AverageIf` function, but I am not understanding what to use for the criteria since it itself is a range to find the customer names in column 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using a **Pivot Table.**

Comment: Can i do that with the data already in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the syntax for AVERAGEIF, the first range is the names, the second value is a cell where you put the specific customer name (could just be a quoted string), and the third value is the range of values to be averaged, so:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A7,I20,E1:E7)
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't try that.